# gulp automatic version for package.json

Tags: node.js, git, gulp

I would like to know if its possible to get the git version for my package.json

What i want to achieve is that i don't need to bump the version manually.

There is something like that in Java with gradle f.e.

https://github.com/palantir/gradle-git-version

It is using git describe to get the latest tag of the git repo and if it contains new commits/changes the repo is marked as dirty. On the dirty check it automatically returns the next development version for gradle.

I didn't find anything like that for gulp

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Check this npm module https://www.npmjs.com/package/git-version-json

You can use `gulp-replace` and `git-version-json`

1. use `git-version-json` to generate the json variable.
2. use `gulp-replace` to replace the `version`

As below:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var replace = require('gulp-replace');
var GitVersionJson = require('git-version-json');
// automatic use git-rev in version field of package.json
gulp.task('npm-git-rev', [GitVersionJson.task], ()=>{
    return gulp.src('package.json')
        .pipe(replace(/(\"version\"\s*:\s*\"\d+\.\d+\.)(\d+)(\")/,
            "$1" + GitVersionJson.gitVer.rev + "$3"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.'))
});
```

run it with `gulp npm-git-rev`